# Lua: Expression from metatable returns nil instead of false

Tags: lua, expression, metatable

I have a metatable set up like this example:

```
    setmetatable(self, {
    __index = function(_,k)
        return Class[k] and Class[k](self, ref) or ref[k]
    end
})
```

And my function:

```
function Class:isDriving(person)
   return (person.onRoad and person.inCar) or false
end
```

All together it allows me to do something like this:

```
print(driver.isDriving)
```

Now this all works, When the expression is true it returns a boolean **true**. 
The only problem I have is that the expression returns **nil** when its false, instead of just a boolean **false**.

```
--I tried this too, but also returns nil
return (person.onRoad and person.inCar) or (nil and false)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `Class[k](self, ref)` may return `false`
Rewrite

```
return Class[k] and Class[k](self, ref) or ref[k]
```

as

```
if Class[k] then
   return Class[k](self, ref)
else
   return ref[k]
end
```

Comment: Interesting, your solution solved the problem. I still dont fully understand what is different. My oneliner versus yours does basically the same right?

Comment: @RichardAvalos - Not the same.  Lua ternary expression `cond and A or B` doesn't work as you expecting when `A = false`